# Is delta temperature dependent on the initial temperature?

Tags: temperature

All computer hardware testing sites i know test cooling solutions (CPU/GPU coolers) based on the temperature difference from the initial (room) temperature. This is a good way to compare, but i don't know if it's accurate.

So, two different systems that have been tested in different room temperatures can be comparable simply by the change in temperature? In other words, the same system will show the same temperature difference if tested in different room temperatures? And if not, how can we compare them?

Comment: You're asking about the temperature dependence of [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity). Without more specific information about the materials and temperature ranges used, this is pretty much unanswerable (and with information, it becomes an exercise in looking up the heat capacity curves). However, for many purposes it is completely fine to treat the heat capacity as constant.